# How to display apostrophe ' in faces message added via OmniFaces Messages#add

Tags: jsf, message, omnifaces, apostrophe

I am using `p:messages` for display error no UI in primefaces `XHTML` page.
I want to display String like Employee's. When I am trying to use OmniFaces `Messages` utility, it is not showing. For more detail look code below.

XHTML:

```
<p:messages id="globalMessages" autoUpdate="false" closable="true"
                escape="true" showDetail="true"/>
```

Bean:

```
Messages.add(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "global", "employee's");
```

Presentation:

[image]

It works when I use plain `FacesContext#addMessage()`:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Info", "PrimeFaces Rocks employ's"));
```

Presentation:

[image]

But I have to use `Messages.add(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "global", "employee's");`

How is this caused and how can I display the single quote in the message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in [javadoc](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/2.4/org/omnifaces/util/Messages.html), the default resolver of OmniFaces `Messages` uses `MessageFormat` API to format messages, exactly like as how `<h:outputFormat>` and resource bundles work.

In [`MessageFormat` API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html), the single quote is a special character and needs to be escaped with another one if you want to represent it as-is.

```
Messages.add(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "global", "employee''s");
```

Alternative is to use a curly quote instead.

```
Messages.add(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "global", "employee’s");
```

Or to register a custom message resolver which does nothing with the message.

```
Messages.setResolver(new Messages.Resolver() {
     public String getMessage(String message, Object... params) {
         return message;
     }
 });
```

But then you can't use message parameters anymore.

---

**Update**: I have just improved the `Messages` utility to not perform any formatting if there are no message parameters in first place. You can see the enhancement in [this commit](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/commit/81077f25aa41bfa9734b86ac85fffeca732d2437). It's available in today's latest [2.5-SNAPSHOT](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/omnifaces/omnifaces/2.5-SNAPSHOT/).

Comment: Thank You @BalusC, it work and get some knowladge about Omniface